# Moq verify contents of List parameter that is passed to method

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I am using Moq and want to verify the contents of a List parameter that is passed to the method.

Now how can I verify if the called Write Method,

```
public class DBStore
{
    public virtual void Write(string retailName, List<CustomerInfo> list, List<Order> orderList)
    {

    }
}
```

had Customer Name "a" and the count?

```
public class CustomerInfo
{
    public string Name;
    public int CustomerInfoId;
}
```

I am able to verify string but not contents of a given list or the count.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestCustomer()
    {
        var dbStore = new Mock<DBStore>();

        dbStore.Setup(x => x.Write(
            It.IsAny<string>(),
            It.IsNotNull<List<CustomerInfo>>(),
            It.IsNotNull<List<Order>>()));

        var updateInfo = new UpdateInfo(dbStore.Object);

        updateInfo.UpdateCustomer();

        dbStore.Verify(
            o => o.Write(
                "Walmart",
                It.IsNotNull<List<CustomerInfo>>(),
                It.IsNotNull<List<Order>>()));
    }
}
```

Can I use IsAny<> in the Verify method? If so, how?

Supporting classes:

```
    public class Order
    {
        public int CustomerInfoId;
        public string Details;
        public int OrderId;
    }


    public class UpdateInfo
    {
        public DBStore DB { get;set; }

        public UpdateInfo(DBStore dbStore)
        {
            this.DB = dbStore;
        }

        public void UpdateCustomer()
        {

            // Logic to get some more info and get retail name
            string retailName = "walmart";
            List<CustomerInfo> customerList = new List<CustomerInfo>();
            customerList.Add(new CustomerInfo { Name = "a", CustomerInfoId = 1 });
            customerList.Add(new CustomerInfo { Name = "b", CustomerInfoId = 2 });

            List<Order> orderList = new List<Order>();
            orderList.Add(new Order { OrderId = 1, CustomerInfoId = 1 });
            orderList.Add(new Order { OrderId = 2, CustomerInfoId = 1 });

            this.DB.Write(retailName, customerList, orderList);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "count" should be? Count of the customers? Count of the customers with the name "a"? Count of the orders for customer "a"? If the criteria can be scoped exclusively to the customer list you'd probably do this with `It.Is<T>` and specifying the matching criteria e.g., `It.Is<List<CustomerInfo>>(x => x.Count(y => y.Name.Equals("a")).Equals(1))` will assert that the customer info list had 1 customer with the name "a".